# Observe property change multiple times in one WPF event using MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I was wanting to do a costly operation and post back to a user 'where' in the state of operation a method was.  Basically I am using MVVM to bind an ICommand to a button click event.  That event triggers a dialogue for a user, the file they select then is a word document that is parsed, then a form is filled with that word document.  The problem I run into with standard operation is that Text displays only the LAST change to the property.  I have set breakpoints and I see that the property gets raised, however it seems that ICommand argument waits till ALL WORK is finished and then updates only the last property.  Is there a way around this to show posts backs to a user, while the process is happening?

**So essentially what I want is a user to click a button and see "Obtained Word Document", (work then is done) "Parsed Word Document" one after the other as the process completes.  NOT the last change when the ICommand finishes.  I think the core issue is that the UI is not getting the changes till the stack pauses that is inside either a 'Relay Command'/'Async Relay Command' delegate method. **

XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding WordFileLocation}" />
<Button Content="Start Process" Height="20" Command="{Binding AsyncDoCommand}"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text, IsAsync=True}" />
```

VIEWMODEL:

```
    private Reader _wordReader = new Reader();
    private string _ParsedWordString;
    private AsyncRelayCommand _DoAsyncCommand;
    private string _Text;
    private string _WordFileLocation;

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _Text; }
        set
        {
            _Text = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Text");
        }
    }

    public string WordFileLocation
    {
        get { return _WordFileLocation; }
        set
        {
            _WordFileLocation = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("WordFileLocation");
        }
    }

    public ICommand AsyncDoCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_DoAsyncCommand == null)
            {
                _DoAsyncCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(async () => await DoIt());

            }

            return _DoAsyncCommand;
        }
    }

    public async Task DoIt()
    {            
        WordFileLocation = "Somewhere a dialogue selected...";
        Text = "Looking....";

        await Task.Delay(2000);
        Text = "Look at me";  // Works FINALLY....

        await GetWordData();  
        // If I put in the delay below, the Text change will show up.  If not it won't.  For some reason my setting of Text DOES not show up till a delay is triggered.
        //await Task.Delay(100);

        await ParseWordData();
    }

    async Task ParseWordData()
    {
        try
        {
            _ParsedWordString = _wordReader.ReadWordDocWithForms(_WordFileLocation);
            Text = "Parsed Word Document";
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Text = "Could not parse Word Document";
        }
    }

    async Task GetWordData()
    {
        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.Multiselect = false;
        dlg.Filter = "Doc Files (*.doc, *.docx)|*.doc;*.docx";

        // open dialog
        bool ok = (bool)dlg.ShowDialog();

        if(ok)
        {
            try
            {
                // Get the location from the dialog
                WordFileLocation = dlg.FileName;
                Text = "Obtained Word Document.";
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Text = "Failed Loading Document.";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Text = "Could Not Browse for Document.";
        }
    }
```

**EDIT 8-20-14 12:45 PST:**
Tseng is correct except for one thing.  I cannot get the UI to accept the async changes UNLESS I force a 'Task.Delay(100)'.  It is like the stack wants to auto finish through my two sub methods.  I am a total noob at the .NET 4.5 async methods, but I want to use them as they seem to be the preferred way.  I am guessing it is my ignorance in understanding the 'Task' and what it does.  I have to do a Task return but it seems await does not like to do something as simple as 'await "Loaded"' or similar.  So I have tried return types in my signature method like 'void', Task, Task with a simple 'return "Obtained Document"'.  None of this updates the Property, UNTILL I call Task.Delay() AFTER the sub method.  So it is my ignorance of understanding the async process of why I need to pause to just get an update.  The 'ParseWordDocument' is pretty expensive as it is parsing long word documents and on average takes 2 to 5 seconds depending on the doc size as it is parsing out form fills as well as plain text.  However even with this delay my text is not getting updated till this sub method is done.

Comment: I suspect your issue is that `_wordReader.ReadWordDocWithForms(...)` isn't async. Async method is one which has either `public async string ReadWordDocWithForms(...)` as signature or `public Task<string> ReadWordDocWithForms(...)` (which is the same). If it's `public string ReadWordDocWithForms(...)` then it's **NOT** async, but sync. Only the instruction with `await` is run asynchronumously. Everything between two `async` calls is run on the thread which started the Task (in this case UI thread, since the View started it)

Comment: No it is doing that.  Above I amended my code to now use methods: 'async Task GetWordData()' and 'async Task ParseWordData()'.  The issue is that for some reason they do not show property changes till the Task.Delay is called.  I also know if I try to return a Task<string> in the signature, async does not like doing an 'await (string)' it complains about how it cannot return it that way.  So only a 'return (string)' seems to work.  Again I am ignorant of all the new 'Task/async/await' methods new to .NET 4.5.

Comment: Yea, but 'public async Task<string> SomeMethod()` doesn't return `string`, it returns `Task<string>`. You either use `public async string` **OR** `public Task<string>`. The compiler translates `async type` into `Task<string>` and `async Task<string>` gets translated into `Task<Task<string>>´

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you to use an async command implementation, like `AsyncRelayCommand` found on the internet.

I use this implementation for one of my own MVVM Projects.

```
public class AsyncRelayCommand : ICommand {
    protected readonly Func<Task> _asyncExecute;
    protected readonly Func<bool> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public AsyncRelayCommand(Func<Task> execute)
        : this(execute, null) {
    }

    public AsyncRelayCommand(Func<Task> asyncExecute, Func<bool> canExecute) {
        _asyncExecute = asyncExecute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) {
        if(_canExecute == null) {
            return true;
        }

        return _canExecute();
    }

    public async void Execute(object parameter) {
        await ExecuteAsync(parameter);
        // notify the UI that the commands can execute changed may have changed
        RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    protected virtual async Task ExecuteAsync(object parameter) {
        await _asyncExecute();
    }
    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged() 
    {
        CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
    }
}
```

This has the additional benefit, that you can't only run the command async and do UI operations inbetween (i.e. add to ObservableCollection) but you can also notify the UI when the CanExecute status may be changed (i.e. when the command is finished).

Example usage:

```
public ICommand DoCommand
{
    get
    {
        if(_DoCommand == null)
        {
            _DoCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(DoIt);
        }

        return _DoCommand;
    }
}

public async void DoIt() {
    WordFileLocation = "Someplace a dialogue selected";
    await ParseDocument();

    Text = "Parsed Word Document";

    await ObtainDocument();
    Text = "Obtained Word Document.";  
}
```

**Edit:**
WPF Command bindings are async/Task aware. If your `ICommand.Execute` returns `Task` or `Task<T>`, then WPF will run them asynchronously.

You really need to make **sure** that both, criteria are met:

1. Your `DoIt()` Method has the `async` keyword (C# 5.0/.NET 4.5) (or returns `Task` rather than being `void`, for .NET 3.5 and 4.0)
2. You use `await` for **EVERY** long processing. If your method returns an `awaitable`/`Task`/`Task<T>` you can await on it. If your methods doesn't, you can still create a new `Task` and await it

Another example of the `DoIt()` Method

```
public Task ParseDocumentAsync() 
{
    return Task.Run( () => {
        // your long processing parsing code here
    });
}

public async void DoIt() {
    WordFileLocation = "Someplace a dialogue selected";

    Text = "Begin";
    await ParseDocumentAsync(); // public Task ParseDocumentAsync() { } 
    Text = "ParseDocumentDone()";

    Text = "Wait 3 seconds";
    await Task.Delay(3000);

    Text = "Run non-Task methods";
    Task.Run( () => LongRunningNonAsyncMethod(); );

    Text = "LongRunningNonAsyncMethod() finished. Wait 2 seconds";

    // DON'T DO THIS. It will block the UI thread! 
    // It has no await, it runs on the thread which started everything, 
    // which is UI Thread in this case, because the View invoked the command.
    // That's why it locks the UI
    Thread.Sleep(2000); 

    Text = "Waited 2 seconds. We won't see this, because UI is locked";
    // DON'T DO THIS, it will ALSO block the UI Thread. 
    LongRunningNonAsyncMethod(); 

    Text = "Finished";  
}
```

On a side note: If you are using .NET 4.5 and C# 5.0, you can use `async`/`await` keywords for async operations. If you are forced to  use older Frameworks (.NET 3.5 and 4.0), you can still use `Task t = Task.Run(...)` to start it and `t.ContinueWith( () => { Text = "Finished" } )´ to execute code after the task is finished.

**Edit2:**
Sorry for the late reply, I was busy with RL work, didn't had much time to watch in here. I'll update your `ParseWordData()` method and hope it works then.

```
// alternatively: async void ParseWordData(). 
// async void => Task as return type
// async Task => Task<Task> as return type
Task ParseWordData() 
{
    return Task.Run( () => {
        try
        {
            _ParsedWordString = _wordReader.ReadWordDocWithForms(_WordFileLocation);
            Text = "Parsed Word Document";
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Text = "Could not parse Word Document";
        }
    });
}
```

This will run the ReadWordDocWithForms code inside a thread/Task and return the `Task`. The `Task` can be awaited.

Basically it boils down to: use await on awaitable methods (which return `Task` or `Task<T>`) and if you need to run a method which isn't awaitable, use `Task.Run(...)` and return (or await) this `Task`.

Comment: This is more along the lines of what I was thinking of.  However the problem still exists with the single property that it is not getting updated on the UI.  I found an article that is more like what I was wanting, however it is not telling me how to do specific async states.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630647.aspx

Comment: This also, unless I am missing something is not raising the changes as the user sees them.  I think the core issue is that the UI is not getting the changes till the stack pauses that is inside either a 'Relay Command'/'Async Relay Command' delegate method.  EG: If I try to change Text = "Obtained Word Document", then raise a dialogue, magically my Text will now show "Obtained Word Document".  If I don't raise anything that stops work, it continues through changes till "Parsed Word Document".  So something is required to force UI to see propagated changes.  I just don't know what attribute.

Comment: I just tried it, it works for me. .NET 4.5 WPF Application, no MVVM Frameworks. Are you using awaitable Methods inside it? If you don't use awaitable Methods inside it, it will lock your UI. The notifications are propagated in your Properties via `RaisePropertyChanged("WordFileLocation")`

Comment: Thanks, that rule you said about System.Threading.Thread.Sleep() is what I was doing.  However the issue is solved if my 'Text' is updated in the 'DoIt' methods but NOT in the sub methods.  See my updates for a better example.  Also I don't know if it was a typo but your AsyncRelayCommand only accepted new AsyncRelayCommand(async () => await DoIt() ); for me NOT what you typed above, (param => DoIt());

Comment: Sorry about that typo. At the time I wrote the initial answer, I was at work where I don't have Visual Studio and hence couldn't test the code for compiler errors. You can actually also shorten it to `new AsyncRelayCommand(DoIt)` since `DoIt()` already has the correct signature. Use `new AsyncRelayCommand(async () => ... )` only for anonymous methods or to call more than one async method but w/o creating a new Class method for it

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to add just a comment so I'll go with an answer.
The ICommand will use the base UI thread to do its processing, so you will not be able to accomplish this without setting up a task of some sort.

It sounds like you know how to do that but in case, this is how I would do it:

```
Text = "Parsed Word Document";
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    //do your "DoIt" work here
    Text = "Obtained Word Document."; 
});
```

Edit:

```
public ICommand DoCommand
{
   get
    {
        if (_DoCommand == null)
        {
            _DoCommand = new RelayCommand(Param => NewMethod(new Action(()=>DoIt())));
        }

        return _DoCommand;
    }
}

NewMethod(Action DoIt)   
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        DoIt.Invoke();
    });
}
```

The Linq statement in the RelayComand Is a bit messy, but this does allow you to reuse "NewMethod" in any place you need to pop off a task.
Otherwise, you could simply call DoIt() from the newmethod and save yourself the Action parameter.

Comment: Where do you suggest I add this?  If I am doing a relay command it can be an extension and either calling this and inputting the property updates directly it accomplishes the same thing as before and does the same thing.  Are you saying to do this in the code behind versus in the RelayCommand being returned?

Comment: I would place it in its own method that calls DoIt() and use this new method as the Parameter of your relay command. You could also create a tasking method that you use for multiple commands and pass an Action/Func which it will process.

I've edited my answer.

Comment: This is only wrapping up an action in yet another method.  It does not get around issue that ICommand seems to limit changes of last change to a property.  EG: Text will equate to "Obtained Word Document" and never show "Parse Word Document".  I can set breakpoints and see the 'set' operation of my property will get hit and 'raised' but it will not be bubbled up to the UI till method is done  Your method runs fine, but it is not doing what I want which is showing async changes to a property.  I think it is a limitation of the 'Relay Command' typically set up in most MVVM patterns.